# Avoid relative path import hell in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native coming from vue background, one thing I hate in react is having to use relative path imports in my components, I find myself doing something like:

```
import HomeScreen from '../../components/screens/HomeScreen'
```

If my folder structure changes it means I will have to do a search and replace in all of m components using that component, not cool and prone to be a dev hell.

Is it possible to use absolute paths like with node modules, is there a library where I can use aliases or similar, with vue I could import my components in the app.js like Vue.component('home-screen ...) and I could use them without having to import.

Answer (score 13):

you can add a `package.json` file with a name key

```
{
  "name": "@components"
}
```

in any folder and metro will recognize it.

You can then import as `@components/screens/HomeScreen`

If you are using vscode, you can add a jsconfig.json file to your project root to enable import autocomplete.

Here is mine:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@helper/*": ["src/helper/*"],
      "@actions/*": ["src/actions/*"],
      "@constants/*": ["src/constants/*"],
      "@primitives": ["src/primitives/index.js"],
      "@graphql": ["src/graphql/index.js"],
      "@services/*": ["src/services/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["assets/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## The easy method

Add a package.json to important directories with a `{"name":"<prefix>"}`, similar to a monorepo.

> If you are doing this, you can probably also think about making it a full monorepo since there is very little extra work

## The incredibly complex method

> This method is easier for using things like webpack resolver, etc.

Create a **metro.config.js** at the root with the following content

```js
module.export = {
    resolver: {
        resolveRequest: (
            context: ResolutionContext,
            moduleName: string,
            platform: string | null
        ) => {
            //...
            return Resolution;
        }
    }
}
```

### Resolution Context

The resolution context is an object that holds attributes of the running resolution, most importantly `originModulePath` which is the path of the requiring module.

### Resolution

The resolution is an object of either:

1. `{ type: "empty" }` for empty sources
2. `{ type: "sourceFile", filePath: string }` for JS, JSON, etc. files
3. `{ type: "assetFiles", filePaths: string[] }` for any other type (e.g. not metro compilable)

> For this method, I would recommend looking at [`metro-resolver`'s types](https://github.com/facebook/metro/blob/master/packages/metro-resolver/src/types.js) since this method is abysmally documented